# c++ pass formatted string as argument to a function

Tags: c++

OK, this really shouldn't be difficult, but after several attempts, I didn't find any solution.

How can one go about passing a formatted string to a function in 1 line? I want to have a simple method that I can use for logging/debugging purposes, something like this:

```
void debug(string s){
    if (DEBUG) cerr << s;
}
```

I would like to be able to send formatted strings to this function, something like this:

```
debug("reading %s" % fname);
```

My main goal is to put as much functionality in the debug method so I can make life somewhat easier whenever I want to write stuff to stderr.

printf solutions seem to need a lot of code for simple formatting and boost::format seems to return some vague type that cannot be easily used as an argument without always including some .str() stuff.

Am I too lazy to be a C++ programmer or is there a neat way of accomplishing this goal that I have yet to discover?

Comment: IMO...too lazy...;) to be serious that's C++ way, C-style printf with boost::format is an option. The other one is simply to use " + " to concatenate them (if at least one is std::string).

Comment: You don't want to create the string (expensive) until you've decided or not that the DEBUG flag is on and you really need to print something.

Answer (score 5):

You can define a macro around fprintf using __VA_ARGS__:

```
#define DBGLOG(format, ...) if(DEBUG){ fprintf(stderr, "%s -- %d -- ", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__); fprintf(stderr, format, ##__VA_ARGS__);}
```

This will, if DEBUG is true, output the function name and line number followed by whatever you wanted to print.

ex:

```
DBGLOG("%d\n", some_integer);
```

This will prepend the function and line number to the integer value and print it out.

Comment: If I may suggest to use `\` to split the macro across several lines and make it more readable.

Comment: This gives me a warning at compile time: "cannot pass objects of non-POD type 'struct std::string' through '...'; call will abort at runtime" and indeed at runtime: "Illegal instruction".

Comment: You cannot pass a std::string to fprintf, it requires a C string. If you have a std::string S then you must pass in S.c_str() to fprintf to print it. An example:
std::string S = "asdf";
DBGLOG("%s\n", S.c_str());

Comment: OK and what is the added advantage of this over the other suggested solutions?

Comment: On the up side: this will compile under C and C++ (the other solutions are C++ only), it will be faster, it will require less code to produce output, and it is easier to format arguments. On the down side: Variable argument lists have no safety (compilers will usually emit a warning but still compile if the argument list doesn't match the format string) and it is not extensible.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that takes in the format and passes it to your other function:

```
void debug( std::string s )
{
    if (DEBUG) cerr << s; 
}

void debug( boost::format format )
{
     debug( format.str() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal C++ solution here is a bit different: your `debug`
function should return a wrapper around `std::cerr` (or any
other output stream), something like:

```
class OStreamWrapper
{
    std::ostream* myStream;
public:
    OStreamWrapper( std::ostream* init ) : myStream( init ) {}
    template <typename T>
    OStreamWrapper& operator<<( T const& value )
    {
        if ( myStream != nullptr ) {
            *myStream << value;
        }
    }
};

OStreamWrapper
debug()
{
    return OStreamWrapper( DEBUG ? &std::cerr : nullptr );
}
```

You then use it:

```
debug() << "reading " << fname << '\n';
```

This has the added advantage that the actual conversions
necessary to format the output aren't done unless debug is
active.

Comment: ... but you cannot avoid the different components (in between the `<<`) to be evaluated.

Comment: @jsantander No, but they're usually just variables for this sort of thing.  (There are more complicated solutions which do avoid it.)